# Reconciling Show/Hide JQuery Script into PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, function, button

I currently have some php script that outputs results from a query. I would like to add at the end two buttons that will show/hide the final element, but am not sure how to do this.

The following is my php script:

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($iname))
{
echo "<b>Event Name:</b> " .$result['EventName'];
echo "<br> ";
echo "<b>Location:</b> ".$result['Location'];
echo "<br>";
//this is where I would like to add my two buttons, that would show the "hidden" content when clicked
```

And here is what I have written in an HTML script, that I would like to reconcile into the PHP output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<scriptsrc="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#hidden").hide();

$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#hidden").hide(500);
});
$("#show").click(function(){
    $("#hidden").show(500);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="show">Show</button>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>

<p id="hidden">

Some Random Text that will be shown when the buttons are clicked

</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions as to how this should be done?

Answer (score 1):

How about if you get the number of result rows with $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
Then, put a counter in your loop.

```html
    $counter = 1;
    $theClass="";
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($iname))
    {
    
    if ($counter ==  mysql_num_rows($result);){
    $theClass="showHide";
    }
    echo "<div class='$theClass'>";
    echo "<b>Event Name:</b> " .$result['EventName'];
    echo "<br> ";
    echo "<b>Location:</b> ".$result['Location'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "</div>

    $counter++;
    }
```

Then, apply your javascript to the div whose class="showHide"